# React: How to set state of object property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner with React and I have been using the NPM package react- 
   tabs in order to display tabs on my site.

I have been trying to allow the 
   user to update descriptions of their profiles using a checkbox to open an input type=text tag allowing the user to put in their own details for their profile.

However, I am struggling to set the state of the description for the tab using the handleDesc function. I am not sure how I can update the state of the descriptions for each tab. I keep getting the error "A component is changing a controlled input of type checkbox to be uncontrolled."

Can anyone help me?

```
class EditSite extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {About: true,
        "Opening Hours": true,
        Contact: true,
        Menu: false,
        Offers: false,
        "External Links": true,
        tabOptions: {
            About: {desc:'1'},
            "Opening Hours": {desc: '2'},
            Contact: {desc:'3'},
            Menu: {desc:'4'},
            Offers: {desc:'5'},
            "External Links": {desc:'6'},
            }
        }
```

Below is the function (handleDesc) I am struggling with to set the state of the descriptions.

```
handleDesc = (event) => {
    let tabOptions = {...this.state.tabOptions[event.target.name]};
    tabOptions = event.target.value;
    console.log(tabOptions);
    this.setState({tabOptions: [event.target.name]});
}   

 render() {
    const links = [];
    const tabs = [];
    const tabPanels = [];
```

The second input tag is where I would like the user to be able to add their own details to the specific tab.

```
Object.keys(this.state.tabOptions).forEach(name => {
  links.push(
      <div>
      <label key={name}>{name}</label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={this.state[name]}
        name={name}
        onChange={this.handleCheckClicked}
      />
      { this.state[name] === true ? (
      <input
      name={name}
      type='text'
      onChange={this.handleDesc}
      />
      ) : null }
      </div>
  );

  if (!this.state[name]) return;

  const { desc } = this.state.tabOptions[name];

  tabs.push(
    <Tab>
      <h3>{name}</h3>
    </Tab>
  );

  tabPanels.push(
    <TabPanel> 
        {desc}
    </TabPanel>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

SetState wants a new object. So settings just a property of a nested object isn’t possible in that way. What you could do is copying the tabOptions and changing the properties you want before you pass it to setState.

**example**

```
handleDesc = (event) => {

const newTabOptions = {
  ...this.state.tabOptions,
  [event.target.name]: {desc: event.target.value}

this.setState({tabOptions: newTabOptions});
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that this would fix it for me but I am still getting the error regarding the controlled and uncontrolled components which I do not understand.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to resolve this would be to revise that code that binds the `<input />` element's `onChange` handler to the following:

```
links.push(
      <div>
      <label key={name}>{name}</label>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={this.state[name]}
        name={name}
        onChange={ (event) => this.handleCheckClicked(event) /* <-- update this also */ }
      />
      { this.state[name] === true ? (
      <input
      name={name}
      type='text'
      onChange={ (event) => this.handleDesc(event) /* [ UPDATE HERE ] */ } 
      />
      ) : null }
      </div>
  );
```

By declaring an arrow function inline like this:

`onChange={ (event) => this.handleDesc(event) }`

it will set the context of the `handleDesc` function to be the `<EditSite />` component (currently, the context will be the global `window` object). This means that when you access `this.state`, or call a method like `this.setState()` inside of the `handleDesc`, it will work as expected.

For more information on this subtle characteristic of "arrow functions" [see this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this).

### Update

Also, consider updating your `handleDesc` method like so to correctly mutate your state:

```
handleDesc = (event) => {
    let tabOptions = {...this.state.tabOptions[event.target.name]};
    tabOptions = event.target.value;
    console.log(tabOptions);
    this.setState({tabOptions}); // <--- Update this line
}
```

### Update 2

On further investigation (into react's source code), it would see the problem is that your `<input />` element does not have a `checked` attribute when `this.state[name] === true` is satisfied. If you apply a dummy attribute/value pair of `checked={ true }` on the input rendered in the `this.state[name] === true` case, this warning message should stop showing:

```
links.push(
  <div>
  <label key={name}>{name}</label>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    checked={this.state[name]}
    name={name}
    onChange={this.handleCheckClicked}
  />
  { this.state[name] === true ? (
  <input
  name={name}
  type='text'
  checked={ true } /* <-- Update this line, don't include this comment in code */
  onChange={this.handleDesc}
  />
  ) : null }
  </div>
 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but its more the error message I am getting when I am trying to set the state of the object. I have tried using the arrow function but was unsure what to put in the [update here] part of the answer, is this where I would write the statements of the function?

Comment: Hi @JohnMutton the /* [ update here ] */ is an inline comment that is just supposed to draw your attention to the line of code where I have adjusted your original code to resolve the problem - if you update that line of code to this : `onChange={ (event) => this.handleDesc(event) } ` does the component function as expected ?

Comment: Right okay. No it doesn't, I am still getting the error, "A component is changing a controlled input of type checkbox to be uncontrolled." This only happens when the function is called and I am trying to set the state of the object.

Comment: Just tried it now and I'm still getting the same error. It appears to be the    handleDesc function that react doesn't like. For some reason when I try to set the state of the object from the variable     tabOptions created within    handleDesc this is where the error is occurring.

Comment: @JohnMutton just had another look - I wonder if another issue was hidden in plain sight. Just updated answer, does this help?

Comment: Hi Dacre Denny, just tried it again and still getting the same error regarding the controlled and uncontrolled component.

Comment: @JohnMutton I did some further investigation - can you try **Update 2** above and let me know how you get on?

Comment: @DacreDenny Still no good. Full error message I am receiving when I'm typing in the input is "A component is changing a controlled input of type checkbox to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa)".

Comment: @JohnMutton any chance you can post a link to the project on github or something similar?

Comment: @DacreDenny Please see github link https://github.com/johnmutton/connectabiz issue is in the edit site within components folder.